# C# Field Naming Guidelines?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I am going to be working on a bit of C# code on my own but I want to make sure that I follow the most widely accepted naming conventions in case I want to bring on other developers, release my code, or sell my code.  Right now I am following the naming convention that Microsoft has set as they seem to be the most widely accepted.  The one thing they don't mention though is naming for private fields.  For the most part I have seen them named in camelCase like protected fields however that present me with an issue as parameter names should be in camelCase.  Take the following constructor for example:

```
public GameItem(string baseName, string prefixName, string suffixName)
{
    //initialize code
}
```

Now if I use camelCase for the private fields too there is a naming conflict unless I use "this" in order to access the class fields (which I think is against most standards not to mention means more typing).  One solution is to give the parameter a different name but that does not make logical sense to give the same data 2 different names.  The only other solution that I know of that was common in C++ coding is giving private members an underscore at the beginning (_camelCase).  Is that solution commonly accepted with C# coding?  Is there another solution to this problem (like only using properties (which use PascalCase) to access fields, even in the class itself)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx

Comment: Choose one and be consistent! That's what matters...

Comment: I use "this" for private fields.

Comment: I use either `this` or public properties with `protected set` and those have first letter capital. Check out M$ **FxCop** if you can.

Comment: Starting to think about it more and it might make more sense to just access them through properties all the times.  Two reasons I am think this is that 1.  Consistency throughout all the code on how to access fields and 2.  If need to add validation checking, I would have to switch all my code to use properties anyways so might as well do it beforehand.  What do you think using properties all the time?

Comment: Well, I do not use them *all* the time but a lot - always for public access, mostly for protected, usually not for private. You can easily refactor your private fields. You can't just refactor a public field to public property, because when an assembly links to the field, it will look for field instead of a property. And you can't easily change behavior on field access.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Follow the [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(VS.71).aspx).  The [guidelines for field usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc(v=VS.71).aspx) indicate that it should be camelCase and not be prefixed.  Note that the general rule is no prefix; the specific rule is not to prefix to distinguish between static and non-static fields.

> Do not apply a prefix to field names or static field names. Specifically, do not apply a prefix to a field name to distinguish between static and nonstatic fields. For example, applying a g_ or s_ prefix is incorrect.

and (from [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx))

> Do not use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters.

**EDIT**: I will note that the docs are not specific with regard to *private* fields but indicate that *protected* fields should be camelCase only.  I suppose you could infer from this that any convention for private fields is acceptable.  Certainly public static fields differ from protected (they are capitalized).  My personal opinion is that protected/private are not sufficiently different in scope to warrant a difference in naming convention, especially as all you seem to want to do is differentiate them from parameters.  That is, if you follow the guidelines for protected fields, you'd have to treat them differently in this respect than private fields in order to distinguish them from parameters. <strike>I use `this` when referring to class members within the class to make the distinction clear.</strike>

**EDIT 2**

I've adopted the convention used at my current job, which is to prefix private instance variables with an underscore and generally only expose protected instance variables as properties using PascalCase (typically autoproperties). It wasn't my personal preference but it's one that I've become comfortable with and probably will follow until something better comes along.

Comment: The naming guidelines are only concerned about identifiers visible to the outside.

Comment: OK what is more correct: this.employee this._employee or this.m_employee?

Comment: @hellboy see my update I now use an underscore prefix and don't typically use `this.` anymore

Comment: > Internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines

Comment: The new naming guideline _does_ suggest using prefixes. The suggested answer needs to be updated. [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#naming-conventions)
`Use camel casing ("camelCasing") when naming private or internal fields, and prefix them with _.`
`When working with static fields that are private or internal, use the s_ prefix and for thread static use t_.`

Answer (score 62):

`_camelCase` for fields is common from what I've seen (it's what we use at our place and Microsoft [prefer for the .NET Runtime](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/b186c975c02a5ce0b45d86fb99063db127979894/.editorconfig#L71)).

My personal justification for using this standard is that is is easier to type `_` to identify a private field than `this.`

For example:

```
void Foo(String a, String b)
{
    _a = a;
    _b = b;
}
```

Versus

```
void Foo(String a, String b)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

I find the first much easier to type and it prevents me from ever accidentally assigning to the parameter called `a` instead of `this.a`.
This is reinforced by a [Code Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264939.aspx) Maintainability Rule that states:

- [CA1500](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182216.aspx) Variable names should not match field names.

My other reason, is that `this.` is optional (Visual Studio / Code prompts you to remove them) if it doesn't collide with a local variable or parameter name, making knowing which variable you are using harder. If you have an `_` at the start of all private fields, then you always know which is a field and which is has local scope.

Comment: _camelCase for private fields is not suggested by Microsoft (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc(v=VS.71).aspx). In case of naming conflicts between class and method scope, you can use the this keyword to refer to the class member. This is also what Resharper suggests by default...

Comment: I agree with the use of the _camelCase for module level variables or property variables.  But as João Angelo said already the most important thing is to be consistent.  It's not about what the standards are it's that you have them and enforce them.  Koen - Resharper (certainly in v5) uses _camelCase.

Comment: _We _don't _need _your _underscores _here

Comment: If you enable .NET Framework source stepping, or if you use a CLI decompiler tool (such as Reflector or ILSpy) to look at the framework sources, you will notice that even Microsoft has started following this guideline from .NET 3.0+.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti just out of interest, do you have an example class?

Comment: @DaveShaw Any class defined in the new assemblies. For example `System.Windows.DependencyProperty` (on `WindowsBase`) has several private fields in `_camelCase`.

Comment: Basically the entirety of WPF seems to be using `_camelCase` for private fields.

Comment: If you check the source code of `.Net Core`, you will find a lot of places where they use `_xyz` convention.

Comment: Using underscores actually is recommended by Microsoft, though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/identifier-names

Answer (score 25):

Generally there are two widely used ways to name fields (always using *camelCase*):

**Using an underscore prefix**

```
void F(String someValue) {
  _someValue = someValue;
}
```

**Using `this.` to access the field and avoid name conflicts**

```
void F(String someValue) {
  this.someValue = someValue;
}
```

Personally I prefer the later, but I will use whatever convention is set forth by the organization I work for.

Answer (score 22):

**Short answer:** use `_privateField`, i.e. use leading underscore for private fields.

**Long answer:** here goes...

Long long ago, Microsoft used to suggest using `camelCase` for fields. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions). Note when that document was created, 10/22/2008. Pretty ancient.

Recent code base of Microsoft however depicts a different picture.

1. Take a look at the [C# Coding style](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md) of .NET Runtime GitHub repository. #3 is the point under discussion. Here is the relevant part

   > We use `_camelCase` for internal and private fields and use `readonly` where possible.
2. Also take a look at [Coding style of Roslyn repository](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#coding-style) that specifically says that it follows the conventions of .NET Runtime.
3. Take yet another look at the [.NET Standard contributing page](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/archive/CONTRIBUTING.md), which also says (at least for now) to follow the same guide as [.NET CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/), which was a precursor to .NET Runtime.
4. Prior to [consolidation](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/119), [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/contributing.md#dos-and-donts) also suggested following the same guide as CoreFX.
5. Even [WinForms repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20190730034500/https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/Documentation/contributing.md) speaks of using this same standard.
6. I think I have said enough. So, to conclude, if you want to follow the guide that Microsoft suggests, I think you know what to do; use leading underscore for private fields like this: `_privateField`.

**My opinion:** I too personally prefer leading underscore for my private fields - makes it very easily distinguishable, without needing the `this`.

Comment: I get what you are saying.. but why then does Visual Studio `CTRL` + `.` autocomplete feature on a constructor variable do `this.private = private;` ? Then in the rest of the class its pretty obvious that when I do `neo4jRepository` is `neo4jRepository` - So how does `_neo4jRepository` make is any more clear. I do not understand how it makes it easier distinguishable. I get if you use maybe non DI things like count for one thing and a method with count for another thing.. yea `_count` then means this count. But why on earth is everybody doing this with DI. My eyes are bleeding

Comment: This is a matter of convention, nothing more. When you follow a convention, it is easier to understand the code's intention without difficulty - it could be any convention, as long as you are consistent with it. Since more and more people are already _consistently_ using this convention, you better get used to it, otherwise you're eyes only will hurt even more ;-)

Comment: Yea, good convention, especially C# 8 underscore `_` is going to be used for a throw away variables.. good luck with not getting confused with that (start using `__` ? *sigh* ). This overuse of underscore to avoid typing `this.` in the constructor (even though VS auto generates this code for you in 2 keyboard taps) actually results in an exponential amount of more typing since the in the entire class you have to type `_` unnecessarily. I get using `_` when you have method hiding class variables. A legitimate reason for framework designers.. not S.O.L.I.D software devs. Just my opinion.

Comment: I don't see how you relate _throw away_ variable, `_` as you call it, with fields beginning with `_`. The former is just an underscore, used in specific context, while the latter has some more characters following it. And BTW, `_` as variable name is not a C#8 thing, it [dates back even earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308078/c-sharp-variable-name-underscore-only).

Comment: Even more reasons to avoid `_`  

Answer (score 12):

In our shop, we started our first C# project using Microsoft's suggested guideline for private members, i.e.

```
camelCaseFieldName
```

But we soon ran into confusion between private members and parameters, and switched to

```
_camelCaseFieldName
```

which has worked much better for us.

A private member usually has a state that persists outside of a method call - the leading underscore tends to remind you of that.

Also note that using AutoVariable syntax for properties can minimize the need for private backing fields, i.e.

```
public int PascalCaseFieldName { get; set;}
```

For a nice concise set of standards that (mostly) follow the MS guidelines, check out [net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices)

Comment: Note that auto properties still use a private backing field, you just delegated its creation to the compiler rather than declaring it by yourself. The funny thing is - the generated name for the backing field is pretty weird.

For example: The auto generated backing field for the property `Int32 Count { get; set; }` will be named `<Count>k__BackingField`. That's far from any naming guidline, it's even using characters that are invalid for identifiers in C# (but that's okay because you normally never see this unless you use reflection).

Comment: @FlorianS.: and that's also the reason for this weird name, they don't want to introduce naming conflicts with auto generated and invisible variables.

Answer (score 8):

As it was mentioned, [Microsoft Naming Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines) dose **not** cover private fields and local variable naming. And you don't find consistency within Microsoft itself. If you generate class or Disposable pattern in Visual Studio it will create something like

```
public MyClass(int value)
{
    this.value = value;
}
```

or

```
private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposedValue)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Fortunately more and more code was opened by Microsoft, so let's take a look a their repos, e.g. [ASP.NET Core MVC](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/2.2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs)

```
private readonly IControllerActivator _controllerActivator;
private readonly IControllerPropertyActivator[] _propertyActivators;
```

Or [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Queue.cs)

```
private T[] _array;
```

You may say, that it's not actually Microsoft, but .NET Foundation. Fair enough, let's take a look at [Microsoft repos](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Metric.cs):

```
private readonly MetricSeries zeroDimSeries;
```

But here is [ancient Microsoft implementation of MVC](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/ASP.NET-Mvc-2/blob/master/MVC/src/SystemWebMvc/Mvc/Controller.cs)

```
private IActionInvoker _actionInvoker;
```

So **there is not any common practice or official guideline regarding private fields naming**. Just choose one you prefer and stick to it.

Answer (score 3):

The most important thing is to pick one standard and stick with it.  Check out iDesign's C# Coding Standard at [IDesign](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx) (it's a link on the right side).  It's a great document that covers things like naming guidelines.  They recommend using camel case for both local variables and method arguments.

Comment: Our .NET dev teams the IDesign coding standards as well. Juwal can't be wrong, right? :)

Answer (score 3):

We use [StyleCop](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120044622/http://stylecop.codeplex.com:80/) to force consistency throughout our code.  StyleCop is [used within Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sourceanalysis/announcing-the-release-of-microsoft-stylecop) enforce a common set of best practices for layout, readability, maintainability, and documentation of C# source code.

You can run StyleCop at build time and have it generate warnings for style violations.

To answer your specific question, private fields should be in camelCase and prefixed with "this".

Answer (score 2):

[Philips Healtcare C# Coding Standard](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CAYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tiobe.com%2Fcontent%2Fpaperinfo%2Fgemrcsharpcs.pdf&ei=QTczTLnsMoSPOMPArY0B&usg=AFQjCNHKtLQGaNPfLuED8ebBr_YGfkvI_A&sig2=q27UG54CIbg-0e2XWJUKzg)

[MSDN - Eric Gunnerson](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CBcQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Fericgu%2Farchive%2F2004%2F01%2F19%2F60315.aspx&ei=XTczTIrHNsyKONftncYB&usg=AFQjCNGXM7B2qGhAakzPmxb44u9_6vpnhA&sig2=G3Qwi_e86d646VYk5i_EWg)

Edit: I use "this" keyword to access non-static members in C# and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Following Microsoft's naming conventions, private fields should be prefixed with an underscore.

For example:

```
private int _myValue;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Identifiers should not contain underscores (it's one of the warnings from **FxCop**).

Comment: It's recommended by Microsoft in their best practice guide.

Comment: FxCop will not flag a private field starting with an underscore.

Comment: Besides, isn't that for some COM compatibility issue? I see it sometimes in the build reports, but just ignore it. I believe FxCop throws up on linq to sql auto generated classes with _ in public properties.

Comment: FxCop doesn't care about internal identifiers but what's good for external usage should be good for internal one. Also, the underscores look ugly (IMHO).
Underscore prefix did not work for some languages that were to be integrated into framework and for interop.
Also having a class with 15 private fields named _whatever slows intellisense-typing down.

Comment: Also I think I read like 6 years ago in naming conventions that an underscore characters should not be used as a prefix but couldn't find it now on msdn. In any case, M$ programmers use underscores all the time ;). Also, **Ian**, can you link the best practices guide?

Comment: @Ian P: I do not see the recommendation to use underscore prefixes anywhere. Convention only mentions underscores to not use them in classes and such.

Comment: I have found the practice not to use prefixes: `Do not apply a prefix to field names or static field names. Specifically, do not apply a prefix to a field name to distinguish between static and nonstatic fields. For example, applying a g_ or s_ prefix is incorrect.` They do not mention non-public fields specifically, but you get the point.

link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta31s3bc.aspx

Comment: To me, that reads that it is regarding hungarian notation which is not what I'm speaking about. If you read any of the microsoft employee's blogs, they all (well, all of the ones I've seen) prefix private fields with _.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions
>  To differentiate words in an identifier, capitalize the first letter of each word in the identifier. Do not use underscores to differentiate words, or for that matter, anywhere in identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The convention I use to distinguish between private class variables and method parameters is:

```
private string baseName;
private string prefixName;
private string suffixName;

public GameItem(string baseName, string prefixName, string suffixName)
{
    this.baseName = baseName;
    this.prefixName = prefixName;
    this.suffixName = suffixName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had doubts about this and then I decided check github codes of Microsoft. Almost every source code I've looked at had **underscore** usage for private fields.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/ document does not seem to mention about this usage.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ReSharper. It will underline all the places where your names do not confirm to ordinary guidelines, and you can customize it. Plus, of course there's loads and loads of other productivity enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

I do this; it's pretty much in line with MSDN.

```
class MyClass : MyBaseClass, IMyInterface
{
    public event EventHandler MyEvent;
    int m_MyField = 1;
    int MyProperty {
        get {
            return m_MyField;
        }
        set {
            m_MyField = value;
        }
    }

    void MyMethod(int myParameter) {
        int _MyLocalVaraible = myParameter;
        MyProperty = _MyLocalVaraible;
        MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Here's a little more detail:
http://jerrytech.blogspot.com/2009/09/simple-c-naming-convention.html

Comment: I think this was in the guidelines ages ago... at the moment, it definitely is not! I also dislike the implicit access modifiers.

Comment: Yeah, it's true. Most coders skip `_`, `m_`, and `s_` prefixes. Anymore, nobody can't tell the scope of a var by its name. Fact is, most coders have reduced their naming to thisName and ThisName and nothing else. To me, it's not right. But I accept it's most common.

Comment: Besides being an outdated convention, it is as ugly as it can get, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I've done much more with VB than C#, so I guess I carry over some practices (prejudices?) from the former to the latter.

I like the private fields of properties to have a leading underscore - especially in C# due to the case-sensitivity (whose idea was *that* anyway?) And I prefix module-/class-wide variables with "m" as well to reinforce their scope.

If you don't like that, you're *really* not gonna like this: I generally use type prefixes as well (except for property fields) - "o" for Object, "s" for String, "i" for Integer, etc.

I can't really defend this with a peer-reviewed paper or anything but it works for us and means we're not tripped up by casing or field/parameter confusion.

So ...

```
Class MyClass

    Private msClassVariable  As String = ""

    Private _classProperty As Integer = 0
    Property Readonly ClassProperty() As Integer
        Get
            Return _classProperty
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New()

        Dim bLocalVariable As Boolean = False
        if _classProperty < 0 Then _classProperty = 0
        msClassVariable  = _classProperty.ToString()
        bLocalVariable = _classProperty > 0
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I hack the parameter names by the prefix "the" such as theSamplingRate. For me, it makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score -5):

```
private string baseName; 
private string prefixName; 
private string suffixName; 

public GameItem(string _baseName, string _prefixName, string _suffixName) 
{ 
    this.baseName = _baseName; 
    this.prefixName = _prefixName; 
    this.suffixName = _suffixName; 
}
```

Comment: -1. This convention is not posted as best practice anywhere I've seen, and the post is very poorly formatted. On a more personal level, I think the _'s in the method signature significantly clutters the code, and since it is used there and not in the private accessors, it will be visible all over the client classes too, and not just in your code.

Comment: In addition to adding visual complexity to the parameter names, "_" is often used to denote "private" in other programming contexts. Parameter names are part of the public method signature and, thus, should not use an underscore prefix. Also, little differentiates a method parameter from a local variable, so using an underscore for one and no underscore for the other (or, worse, also for local variables) is inconsistent.

Comment: Where did you get this mentioned as _naming guideline_ for C#? The question asks for _guidelines_, not whatever you may be using. And as @Matt described, yours is no standard, and not sensible in any way whatsoever.