# Difference between is X and is X _

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Before C# 7.0, the following code was valid:

```
if(x is X)
{
    //...
}
```

Now, the following is also valid:

```
if(x is X _)
{
    //...
}
```

Accoding to [TryRoslyn](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:features-default/f:r/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcBYAUAB2ACMAbMAYxnJIEMQQYBhGAbzxg5kNIpgDcA9mAAmMALIAKAJSt2necwAeMALwwIqAO5NpOXPPlgAZhOVgGjKXIOz9Ng4oB0kqXvswAvtYPHTMc0wwAPpWdjZsYe4wTi5u9l6RCR5AA===), those code sections generates the same IL. My question is: what's the purpose of the discard operator in pattern matching, if it is not necessary neither useful? Am I missing something here?

This question is not the same as [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920622/c7-underscore-star-in-out-variable) one, since I'm asking the purpose of the discard operator (wildcard) specifically for the pattern matching (`is` operator).

Comment: Is this question specifically for `is` or do you just want to know where the `_` wildcard could come in handy?

Comment: @epickip specifically for `is`

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways of writing code that isn't useful.  It's not C#'s job to *prohibit* you from writing code that isn't useful to you.  It couldn't do so even if it *tried*.  C#'s job is to *allow* you to write code that *is* useful.

Comment: @Servy this feature was introduced recently, I'm just asking _why_

Comment: @Logerfo The feature is not strictly the ability to write that one exact line of code.  You're combining the use of multiple different features in one very specific context, to create something that you don't think is useful *in that one specific usage*.  If you want to see what each of the various features you're using are used for, or other (possibly more useful) ways of using them, then simply searching for information on them will give you all of that.

Comment: @Logerfo Can you give the link of Microsoft's page where something like this is used?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker here both `is` and wildcard is used, but not together https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Comment: Is that *actually* the "discard_pattern"? https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/cd7964ed24a5d787cf20a2cc412aa8d85955ea82/proposals/patterns.md that simply appears to be the "type_pattern" where the variable name is an underscore.

Comment: @Will I belive it is the discard operator, because I can have this multiple times in the same scope. Also, Visual Studio shows the `_` in blue, not in white

Comment: `because I can have this multiple times in the same scope` example pls.  Unsure if the color of something in VS (is c# 7 completely supported by 2017?) is proof of anything.

Comment: NVM the example, I see you can nest that discard whereas you cannot override a variable defined this way in a nested scope.  Anyhow, this is all speculation (and better asked over on GitHub), but if I were to wager I'd say it's for the benefit of tool designers in order to make code generation easier.  But I can't say, because I wasn't involved in the process.

Comment: @Will the example is in the try roslyn link in my question. If you change both underscores to `a`, for example, that would result in a compilation error

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18947

Comment: If they added the syntax so that `if(x is X newVar)` which is useful when you want to act on `newVar` then by consequence, you would also be able to use `_` to discard the value.

Comment: @DavidG apparently I can just use _nothing_ to discard the value, which is simpler

Comment: Yes, but the syntax comes from the new feature, the fact that you can use it in this circumstance is just an artefact of that. Nobody is suggesting that you would ever use it, just that it's possible. Just like doing `ToString()` on a string is possible, but pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Neal Gafter](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/18947#issuecomment-296835567), the discard operator *in this case* it's pretty much useless, at least for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not useful yet. But when recursive pattern matching is introduced (hopefully in C# 8.0), it will be useful to have discards in part of the pattern.

The details are not finalized, but imagine something like `is (1, (_, 3))` or possibly `is X (1, Y (_, 3))`.