# out var _ and out _ difference?

Tags: c#, var, out, c#-7.0

In C# 7 we can do like this:

```
byte.TryParse(p.Value, out _)
```

or like this

```
byte.TryParse(p.Value, out var _)
```

Are there any differences?

Comment: Yes there's a difference.  Have you written the same piece of code using both, and actually got it to compile?

Comment: In first syntax you will have to declare `_` separately before calling this, in second syntax it will be declared as well.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: It's not necessary to pre-initialize a variable used as an `out` parameter, although `ref` parameters do have to be definitely assigned prior to the call.

Comment: Seconds before I posted an answer.... [What's new in c# 7.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/) covers it.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks, correcting my comment, declare only.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I disagree that this one is a duplicate (at least not of the one that it's marked to be a dupe of), `_` are ommitted `out` parameters as of C# 7.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't see how duplicate answers this question. So, what's the difference here?

Comment: I agree with Paul.

Comment: _ is for discards, this has a good answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920622/c7-underscore-star-in-out-variable

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara Yes, but this one is still different, since it explicitly asks about the difference between `out _` and `out var _` (spoiler: there is none)

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara Alright, it's covered in the accepted answer, but still: The scope of the question is different.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sometimes `out` parameters are not needed. As of version 7, C# supports an `out` parameter that is a "throw-away" parameter, `_`. It will not (and cannot) be used. This is a good thing to tell your reader that the parameter is not used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As opposed to what others in their comments said: No, there are no differences. They both produce the exact same IL.

Both

```
byte.TryParse(p.Value, out _);
Console.WriteLine(_);
```

and

```
byte.TryParse(p.Value, out var _);
Console.WriteLine(_);
```

will produce a compiler error with C#7, since `_` is not intended to be used.

The usage of `_` is not restricted to out parameters, but can be used for returns, too (as Evk pointed out)

```
byte.TryParse(p.Value, out var _); // I don't care about the out variable
_ = SomeMethod(); // I don't care about the return value
```

There is an excellent answer covering most things about ommitted parameters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42924200/2249175).

**Remarks:** I would prefer `out _` over `out var _`, since there is a clear syntactic distinction between `out _` and `out var legalVariableName`.

**EDIT**

Obviously I'm not quite right here. There are some subtle differences, see Ben Voigts [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801846/2249175).

Comment: `_ = SomeMethod()` is to explicitly express that you do not care about the result (and not acidentally forgot about it). It can be used anywhere (I mean just `void Main() { _ = 123;}` compiles fine without any `out _` and so on, so it's not related to the `out var _` block).

Comment: @Evk Thanks, edited my answer.

Comment: `out var identifier` was legal in some prerelease versions, but not in C# 6.   C# 7 is the first released version that permits out variables (which you called an inline declaration) was allowed.  [Semi-official reference](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/)

Comment: I think you have this backwards: *"With C#6 the former is illegal, but the latter is valid"* (former is first, latter is last)

Comment: This answer is incorrect on several levels.  The lines of code are not equivalent, and the claims about C# 6 are faulty.

Comment: @Rufus: In C# 6 they're both invalid, the first because `_` is an undeclared identifier, the second because `out typename identifier` is illegal syntax.

Comment: @BenVoigt Well, yes, the variable has to be declared somewhere as `byte _;`. Just as whatever `p` is has to be declared. I thought that was assumed, but you have a point.

Answer (score 9):

The difference is how they handle an existing variable named `_`.

```
string _;

int.TryParse("123", out var _); // legal syntax for discard
int.TryParse("123", out _); // compile error, string _ is incompatible with out int parameter
```

or

```
int _;

int.TryParse("123", out var _); // discard
Console.WriteLine(_); // error: variable is not assigned
int.TryParse("123", out _); // passes existing variable byref
Console.WriteLine(_); // ok: prints "123"
```

The reason for this is that `out _` already had a meaning, and the language maintains backward compatibility with that old meaning.  But `out typename identifier` is new syntax in C# 7, so there's no backward compatibility constraint.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, I admit that I haven't thought about that case.