# With C# 7.x syntax additions, is there a version of "x ?? (x = MakeX())", where x is assigned via an out parameter?

Tags: c#, syntax, expression, out, c#-7.0

One idiom in C# to 'create a value on first access'<sup>1</sup> is to use something like the following<sup>2</sup>:

```
public string X {
   get {
       return _x ?? (_x = MakeX());
   }
}
```

Given a slight variation, where `MakeX` is defined as `void MakeX(out string x)` instead of the "standard" `string MakeX()`, is there a way to leverage C# [7] syntax shortcuts?

(There are a million ways to re-write the code<sup>3</sup>; the question is primarily about, if there are any new tricks that allow an 'out statement' to be used in an expression.)

The following does *not* work (it might be worse than that<sup>1</sup>..) but here is the gist:

```
public string X {
   get {
       return _x ?? { MakeX(out _x); _x };
   }
}
```

The semantic *long form* (which is valid..) would look something like:

```
public string X {
   get {
       var x = _x;
       if (x != null) return x;
       MakeX(out x);
       return (_x = x);
   }
}
```

<sup>1</sup>It is assumed that *thread-safety is not relevant* as long as *a value* is returned. No suggestions for `Lazy` :}

<sup>2</sup>The original-style `get` is not in question.

<sup>3</sup>The question is about *new syntax* in particular, not doing "overly clever tricks" with lambdas. As such, `return _x ?? (() => {MakeX(out _x); return _x;})();` would still result in a "no" to the question.

Comment: Wow you took all the fun out of this question

Comment: The answer is no unfortunately. Since `MakeX` is a `void`, you cant use it in a null-coalescing operator without funky lamdas

Comment: If you're willing to define `MakeX` as `string MakeX(out string x)` and make it always return `null`, then you could write this: `return _x ?? MakeX(out _x) ?? _x;`. Note that it's confusing, and you can't really beat the *idiomatic* `return _x ?? (_x = MakeX());`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski In that case, it could be written as `return _x ?? MakeX(out _);` with the ["dummy out" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920622/c7-underscore-star-in-out-variable). I was hoping for / to discover additional 'out'-as-expression support :}