# how to update string "_servername" from the second Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in C# programming, but I know that attributes should be encapsulated in the class. Therefore I used private declaration

```
private string _servername;
```

Problem is that I cannot update `_servername` from 2nd Form. 
I clicked on `ChangeName` button. New `Form2` was appeared. I clicked on button `NewName`. Methods from Form1 were finished successfully and MessageBox in method `_Server2` shown me that value of `_servername` should be "TEST"
When I click on button `CurrentServerName`, value of `_servername` is still "localhost". Could you please tell me why? How to fix it? Thank you in advance

**FORM 1**

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string _servername;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _servername = "localhost";
        }

        public string _Server(string _server)
        {
            _servername = _server;
            string serverlist2 = _server;            
            _Server2(serverlist2);
            return serverlist2;
        }

        public void _Server2(string _server2)
        {
            _servername = _server2;
            MessageBox.Show(_servername);
        }

        private void ChangeName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 _Form2 = new Form2();
            _Form2.Show();
        }

        private void CurrentServerName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_servername);
        }

    }
}
```

**FORM 2**

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NewName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 _Form1 = new Form1();
            _Form1._Server("TEST");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By 'attributes should be encapsulated in a class' I think you mean 'members should be encapsulated in a class'. Attributes are another thing all together http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/11579/1954

Comment: No dramas, glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to create a new instance of `Form1` inside `Form2`. Instead, when you create an instance of `Form2` to show it, pass a reference to the current instance of `Form1` into the constructor. You can then access the methods on the existing instance of `Form1`. Here is an example:

**Form 1**

```
private void ChangeName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Pass a reference to this form instance using the 'this' keyword
    Form2 _Form2 = new Form2(this);
    _Form2.Show();
}
```

**Form 2**

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        // Hold an instance to Form1
        private Form1 mForm1;

        public Form2(Form1 form1)
        {
            // Store instance to form1
            mForm1 = form1;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NewName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Change name on existing instance of form 1
            mForm1._Server("TEST");
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. There are no public attributes. Thank you very much

Comment: @cotabolise: members... not attributes - and attribute is something totally different e.g. `[XmlIgnore]`

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because you are creating a new "instance" of `Form1` inside `Form2`, this is not the same as the other `Form1`.

You need to change Form1 like this:

```
private void ChangeName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.Show();
        _Server(form2.ServerName);
    } //Ensure the form is Disposed.
}
```

And Form2 like this:

```
namespace Test   
{   
    public partial class Form2 : Form   
    {   
        public Form2()   
        {   
            InitializeComponent();   
        }   

        public String ServerName { get; private set; } //Can only be set in this class, but read by all.

        private void NewName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
        {   
            ServerName = "Test";   
            Close();   
        }   
    }   
}
```

EDIT: Another point. Naming methods like `_Server()` and local variables like `_Form2` is bad practice, they shold be `Server()` and `form2`. Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) and also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3186853/383710).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and tips. I will remember it