# How to name associated property and variable?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I want to create private list, while making it public as readonly\unwriteable, unable to add\remove\insert cells\nodes to the list.

My current solution is:

```
public IEnumerable<DataToken> DataTokens {
    get {
        return from v in _datatokens select v;
    }
}
private List<DataToken> _datatokens;
```

I know the property's name is fine, but what about the variable's name? I can't name it `dataTokens` because it's parameter's name's format. Currently I call it `_datatokens` that is really bad name.

Is there a better alternative? I couldn't find anything about it at msdn.

Comment: `dataTokens` and `DataTokens` are two different identifiers in C#. You could name your field `dataTokens`.

Comment: That is not a "really bad name" and this is opinion-based.

Comment: @Dirk It's parameter's name's format. This isn't corrent.

Comment: @CodeCaster In C++ where screaming constant are there, _ is bad.

Comment: What does _"It's parameter's name's format"_ mean? Can you phrase that differently or show relevant code? And what are screaming constants? Anyway prefixing private fields with underscores is pretty common in C#.

Comment: Someone can cast the result to a `List<DataTokens>` and then it wouldn't be readonly anymore...

Comment: @CodeCaster `DataType parameterType, DataType returnType` this is the correct way to type parameters, look at their names, they start with non-capital letter. C++ has `I_MAKE_HORROR` names.

Comment: Why is `_datatokens` a 'really bad name'? I quite often name backing fields using the same convention. What's stopping you from using `dataTokens` as the field name anyway?

Comment: @Dennis_E Just tested it, I will rename it to `ReadOnlyCollection<DataToken>`.

Comment: @DGibbs I am a bit of a nazi grammar in my programming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Field Naming Guidelines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186853/c-sharp-field-naming-guidelines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since identifiers are case-sensitive in C#, there is nothing against `datatokens` as a variable name.

There is a [guideline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043(v=vs.100).aspx) available on MSDN that would suggests it to be `dataTokens` (camel-cased).

By the way, you should use [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx) as return type to make it read-only to the outside world, so I would suggest to split this one up in two properties with different access modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

C# also supports auto-properties, so you can save yourself the trouble of solving this conundrum and simply declare your property thus;

```
public IEnumerable<DataToken> DataTokens { get; private set; }
```

Comment: I need to use it as `List<DataToken>` too.